# java incompatible type error else-if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, return, incompatibletypeerror

I am only trying to compute for the three values and not sure what to put as my else statement. I put return but it just keeps giving me an incompatible type error. I have tried setting it as null, and NaN but it states I cant do that with the type being double. Any help is appreciated.

```
public static double getE(int i) {
    double e = 1, x=1;
    for(i = 1; i <= 100000; i++){
        x=x/i;
        if (i == 10000) {
            return x;
        }
        else if (i == 20000) {
            return x;
        }
        else if (i == 100000) {
            return x;
        } 
        return;
   }  
}
```

Comment: Return a `Double`, this way you can return `null`

Comment: *Curious:* What is the point of passing in parameter `i`, when you then immediately throw the value away?

Comment: *More curious:* How would you expect the two `else if` to ever be true, when you return as soon as `i` reaches 10000, making it impossible for `i` to get to 20000 and 100000? Or actually, since you `return` unconditionally at the end of the loop, `i` will never be more that 1, so even the `if` is meaningless.

Comment: By *"setting it as NaN"* so you mean you tried `return Double.NaN;`? Because that should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Not-a-Number (NaN) holds a value of type `double` which is equivalent to value returned by `Double.longBitsToDouble(0x7ff8000000000000L)` as:-

```
public static final double NaN = 0.0d / 0.0;
```

---

Since in your case, you are using a *primitive type `double`*(which is just data and not an object, hence can't be `null` either), you can make use of those values directly by changing your `return` to

```
return 0.0d;
```

and make sure it's outside of the for loop

```
for (i = 1; i <= 100000; i++) {
    x = x / i;
    if (i == 10000) {
        return x;
    } else if (i == 20000) {
        return x;
    } else if (i == 100000) {
        return x;
    }
}
return 0.0d; // default value, in case the for loop wasn't executed
```

Comment: Are you saying that 0.0 == NaN? Because that's definitely not true.

Comment: @yshavit No I am not comparing them, but stating the relevance to use a default value that I next mentioned to be used.

Comment: But why are you even talking about `NaN`, then? It's not the default value and has nothing to do with this. Saying "`NaN` is equivalent to `0.0d`" is wrong and very misleading.

Comment: Ok, I think you should rephrase the statement that NaN is equivalent to 0.0, then. I'm not sure what you mean by it, if you're not saying they're equal.

Comment: @Andreas Since the OP made a statement of trying to use it.

Comment: *FYI:* Question code has final return statement *inside* the loop.

Comment: @yshavit addressed,  please check

Comment: I don't think showing the bit pattern of a `NaN` is useful to OP, if OP can't even get that code to compile. You're just confusing OP with irrelevant information.

Comment: @Andreas i differ in opinion there, if OP has tried using something, they shall also know what its implementation actually is and should not be irrelevant. Just saying to use `0.0d` in the return without letting them know why exactly that value for a replacement of `NaN` would be injust.

Comment: And where in the answer did you *explain* pros/cons/diff of returning `NaN` vs. returning `0.0d`?

Comment: @Andreas And why should the pros/cons be explained while the primitive type is already in use? Do you expect the differences between reference and primitive types to be listed out there as well?

Comment: OP said that `NaN` was tried and failed to compile *(which shouldn't have happened)*, and you're simply suggesting to return `0.0d` instead, without any explanation of why you think that is a better return value than `NaN`. You might as well have suggested to return `42`, it is the answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything, after all. Why not, it's as distinct from any expected return value as `0`, since only numbers less than `1` would ever be expected.

Comment: *that is a better return value than NaN* because of the current usage of primitive data type by the OP which in itself is not incorrect,isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

your code

```
public static double getE(int i) {
    double e = 1, x=1;
    for(i = 1; i <= 100000; i++){
        x=x/i;
        if (i == 10000) {
            return x;
        }
        else if (i == 20000) {
            return x;
        }
        else if (i == 100000) {
            return x;
        } 
        return;
   }  
}
```

is strictly equivalent to

```
public static double getE(int i) {
   return;
}
```

and the `i` input argument is simply unused.
what are you trying to achieve ?